# How to create dynamic hyperlink in excel?

Tags: excel, google-docs

I want to link to a string (for a table of contents). But when I create a new line, then the link moves out. How to fix a link so that it always leads to the same place and remains in the same place when new lines are added?

[image]

---

I attach a [*GIF*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXkVx.jpg) for a clearer explanation of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use HYPERLINK and CELL

To get a reference to a cell you can use this format for your hyperlink:

```
#gid=0&range=C1
or
#gid=0&range=E6
or
#gid=0&range=Z10
```

So using that information:

In Cell A1:

```
="#gid=0&range=" & CELL("address", C1)
```

This returns `#gid=0&range=$C$1` but we want only `C1` so we use `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
="#gid=0&range=" & SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", C2),"$","")
```

To substitute `"$"` for `""`, which gives `#gid=0&range=C1`

Here you are concatenating the string `"#gid=0&range="` together with the result of `CELL` which returns the address of a cell, except its dynamic!

In Cell B1:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1, "LINK")
```

Since the link comes from the dynamic result of `A1` it is updated dynamically.

---

To get this all in one cell:

In A1:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=" & SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", C1),"$",""), "LINK")
```

Modify `C1` to the reference you want.

#### Docs

- [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313)
- [`CELL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071)
- [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)

Comment: The problem is that when I use `INDIRECT`, the link becomes unclickable, but I need it for the table of contents, so that when clicked, it immediately moves to the desired line and that the lines do not move when new ones are added

Comment: I don't understand. Can you add more screen shots to your question describing the set up and process? Do you mean that if you insert a row, that some values stay in the same place?

Comment: @RoyalGoose I updated the answer with another function, maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Attached the GIF to the question where I clearly demonstrated the essence of the problem. In your answer, you are trying to create a link to a site, but I want to create a link to a cell in order to go to it (to the cell itself). But when I insert new lines, the link moves to another line, and I would like it to be fixed on the cell I selected. Can you demonstrate in your answer how you would make a link to the cell itself, and not to its content (as you do with Google)

Comment: @RoyalGoose I understand now, though it looks like you found a solution, here is another using formulas.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the link from moving, it nesseccary to use named ranges. Add a range to the cell that need to refer to. Then right-click in the table of contents - link, make a link through the named range. Then, when adding columns / rows, the named range also changes and the link always leads to the desired cell.

---

*It is also possible not make named ranges, but simply make a reference to the cell. I.e. do not get a link and insert it into the table of contents, but make a link to a cell in the table of contents, then it moves when rows / columns are added*